# Deploying Visio Viewer with InstallShield: Module VVIEWER.DLL Failed to Register

Tags: visual-studio-2015, deployment, installshield, visio

I have created an application using Visual Studio Professional 2015 (Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3) that utilizes Visio Viewer (Version 16.0.4339.1001).
When I install my application, I get "Error 1904. Module C:\Program Files (x86)...\VVIEWER.DLL failed to register. HRESULT -2147220473. Contact your support personnel."
I have researched and not found a solution. I have done all the basics .. windows is up to date, etc.
In my application I reference AxVisioViewer.
The application does run / work correctly - but I am concerned that the end users will not have a good install experience as they see this error during install.
(I also get the similar error when uninstalling - the failed to deregister error 1905).

Visio Viewer must be installed first. In Visual Studio, AxVisioViewer copy local set to yes (it will not work if set to no). Embed Interop Types - False. Specific version - False.
I have tried uninstalling Visio Viewer and installing my app, it will not run without Visio Viewer installed. I have re-installed visio viewer then re-installed my app - same error during installation. As stated, it works - but the user sees this error.
I am using InstallShield LE, and I am digitally signing my app / setup programs
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED.
Visio Viewer must be installed, therefore VVIEWER.DLL is already installed / registered.
However, in my project, I must have a reference to AxVisioViewer, which is generated when following the instructions
on https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Visio-VBA/articles/about-programming-visio-viewer
for Programming Visio Viewer in Managed Code.
Adding that reference automatically adds that file, as well as VisioViewer.dll and VVIEWER.DLL.
In the install project, under files, I right clicked on {project}.Promary output, and looked at dependencies.  I was able to uncheck VVIEWER.DLL to exclude it from the build.
As that one file is now excluded from the build, it no longer causes the issue.